# How to use django filter_horizontal in frontend?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

i hope you can help me with this, there is a way to use the filter_horizontal outside django 1.9.7 admin?

i have seen that i can include the widget on my forms.py with:

```
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import FilteredSelectMultiple
```

and include it with:

```
class Up(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Up_model
        fields = ('add_doctor')
        labels = {
            'add_doctor': ('Add doctor'),
        }
        widgets = {
            'add_doctor': FilteredSelectMultiple("Groups", is_stacked=False),
        }
```

but with no success, can you help me with this?

Comment: You should follow the Python/[PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) way for naming styles. So it would be `UpModel` instead of `UP_model`.
And you cannot directly use admin widgets outside the admin.

Comment: or there is a way to use a popup for a manytomanyfield on frontend to select and add the choices (llke the + on admin manytomany field )?

Comment: Take a look at [inline formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) - they will basically do most of what you need.

Answer (score 6):

Even if this question is very old, for anyone stumbling over the same issues: I could solve it by adding the following dependencies to the output page. I am using Django 1.11

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'admin/css/widgets.css' %}" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% url 'admin:jsi18n' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/core.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/jquery.init.js' %}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/SelectBox.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/SelectFilter2.js' %}"></script>
```